# Interpolating bash variable containing quotes into a command breaks it

Tags: bash

I'm trying to split out some parts of a docker command that I have into bash variables.

What I had previously, works fine:

```
DOCKER_ID=$(docker run -e CGO_ENABLED=true -e LDFLAGS='-extldflags "-static"' -v $pkgPath:/src ...etc)
```

Putting the `-e` flags into a variable and trying to use that:

```
BUILDER_ARGS="-e CGO_ENABLED=true -e LDFLAGS='-extldflags \"-static\"'"
DOCKER_ID=$(docker run $BUILDER_ARGS -v $pkgPath:/src ...etc)
```

This second version gives me the error:

```
docker: Error parsing reference: "\"-static\"'" is not a valid repository/tag.
```

Which makes me think that the variable I'm trying to interpolate is being mangled somehow.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the value of `BUILDER_ARGS` will not be re-interpreted, and so the escaped quotes are taken literally, without performing their usual function of quoting the enclosed string.
Not escaping the quotes won't work either,
because then in the `docker run` expression, in `BUILDER_ARGS`, the value of `LDFLAGS` will be split at the space.

Using a Bash array should solve these issues:

```
BUILDER_ARGS=(-e CGO_ENABLED=true -e LDFLAGS='-extldflags "-static"')
DOCKER_ID=$(docker run "${BUILDER_ARGS[@]}" -v $pkgPath:/src ...etc)
```

This will work, because each element in the `BUILDER_ARGS` array will be preserved and properly quoted. The last value of the array is `LDFLAGS='-extldflags "-static"'`, like that, as a whole,
and it is preserved well and executed as expected in `docker run`.